# Calculating Intrinsic Estimation Error and Extrinsic Error in Camera Calibration using a sequence of images using OpenCv

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0, camera-calibration

Well, given a sequence of 2d image points for N images and a single set of 3d object points, calibration can be done for a single camera using

```
double calibrateCamera(InputArrayOfArrays objectPoints, InputArrayOfArrays
imagePoints, Size imageSize, InputOutputArray cameraMatrix, 
InputOutputArray distCoeffs, OutputArrayOfArrays rvecs, 
OutputArrayOfArrays tvecs, int flags=0,
TermCriteria criteria=TermCriteria( TermCriteria::COUNT+TermCriteria::EPS, 30, DBL_EPSILON) )
```

Well, this function returns 3x3 Camera Matrix(Intrinsic parameters like focal length, principal points) and various extrinsic parameters like distortion coefficients and rotation vector,etc.

If i wish to estimate Errors for all intrinsic and extrinsic parameters obtained using the above function, what should be the procedure? Basicalluy, what is the way to obtain Calibration Errors in opencv. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition of "Calibration Errors"?

Comment: Error in Estimation of intrinsic and extrinsic parameters of a single/stereo camera while calibration.

Answer (score 0):

Using the newly obtained calibration parameter, project the 3d object point to the image plane and calculate the distance of each projected point with the detected 2d points